# Is this usage of へ wrong?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

> それと同時に、日本の勢力下にあった満洲への研究施設の設置も着手された

Shouldn't に be used here instead of へ? As far as I know, the function of へ is to denote the direction in which an action is taken, not a direction in which an action is taken.

Answer (score 3):

に cannot be used because にの is an invalid combination. On the other hand, への is valid and compatible with 設置(する) probably because 設置 indicates something of direction (*putting ... on**to***).

Note 満洲{へ,で,に}研究施設が設置される are possible. Then nominalizing them requires の after 満州＋particle, so that they become 満洲{への，での}研究施設**の**設置.